# How to solve this deployment errors (Variable does not exist: isReadOnly)?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, failing-tests

Trying to deploy package (big one) to a new org but all the tests failed with very weird errors:

1)line -1, column -1: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class *ClassName* : Variable does not exist: isReadOnly 
Stack Trace: null

2)  line -1, column -1: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class  *ClassName* : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void *MethodName* from the type *MethodType*
Stack Trace: null

Do you know the root cause of the errors?

Comment: Before deployment all the classes were compiled.

Comment: refer this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000229072&type=1

Comment: It can be hard to find the salient points in the error messages when a large deployment fails. This could represent a missing dependency - a custom class or sObject that's not present in the target org. Can you find any other text that describes the "first" error, usually at the head of the log?

Comment: Maybe the type of your readOnly variable is missed.
Please, check it

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to compile all classes and check that if any of the classes in your package returning an error for such errors:

Setup Menu -> Develop -> Apex Classes -> Compile all classes

Comment: I've compiled all the classes before deployment, never the less got this error.